# Why do I get a syntax error in the for-loop definition in this Java program?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm working on the below code to create an `ArrayList`, shuffle it, and take the first three elements but, for some reason, on the line when I start the for loop I get a syntax error on token ";"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class cardsShuffle {


    ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>()

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        cards.add(String.valueOf(i+1));
        java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        cardsShuffle s = new cardsShuffle();

        System.out.println(s.cards.get(0));
        System.out.println(s.cards.get(1));
        System.out.println(s.cards.get(2));

}
```

Comment: 1) you are missing a semi colon after `new ArrayList<>()`.
2) the for loop is not inside any method. you can create a static method with the for loop inside it and initialize the cards list using that method by `ArrayList<String> cards = myStaticMethod();`. 3) Even after the first two there would be an error because static methods cannot reference instance variables. the cards list would have to be static.

Comment: I put the loop inside the the main method then I had to delete s. from he prin.outln  and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the semicolon after the line "ArrayList cards = new ArrayList<>()".Just put a semicolon and your code will be error free :)

Comment: Wrong! There's still a for loop in the class body.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the for loop outside function.  All things other than deceleration should be written inside function or blocks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardsShuffle 
{
public static ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(cards.get(0));
        System.out.println(cards.get(1));
        System.out.println(cards.get(2));
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            cards.add(String.valueOf(i+1));
            java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);
        }
    }
}
```

The code should be something like this...always things to execute inside the function.

Comment: You cannot access a non-`static` field from a `static` method without specifying a instance of the containing class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class cardsShuffle {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i<52;i++)
        {
            cards.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);
        }
        cardsShuffle s = new cardsShuffle();
        System.out.println(cards.get(0));
        System.out.println(cards.get(1));
        System.out.println(cards.get(2));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just put code into a class. It needs to be inside inside a method, constructor or initializer block or the RHS of a field initialisation (not possible for loops).

Furthermore you don't need to shuffle after adding each card. Since `Collections.shuffle` produces a random permutation, using it once after the loop is sufficient.

```
public class cardsShuffle {

    // field declaration
    ArrayList<String> cards;

    // constructor
    public cardsShuffle() {
        cards = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            cards.add(String.valueOf(i+1));
        }

        java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        cardsShuffle s = new cardsShuffle();
        System.out.println(s.cards.get(0));
        System.out.println(s.cards.get(1));
        System.out.println(s.cards.get(2));
    }

}
```